# .net active passive cluster library

Tags: .net, cluster-computing

Is there a library / framework available for use in a .NET environment that takes care of the low level interprocess communication to support active/passive clustering for a cluser with any number of nodes. What I mean is something that (for example) might have the nodes communicating/heartbeating with each other, voting for who is the active node etc.

Comment: Please tag more carefully. This is not [tag:cluster-analysis] (aka clustering, a part of data mining), but you probably wanted [tag:cluster-computing] or [tag:load-balancing] instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at [Creating Cluster-Aware Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369321%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: This on the face of it sounds promising but there is very little information on the site about this. Are there any pieces of example code (.NET?) that show how to use these MS cluster apis?

Answer (score 1):

We've worked some on a master-election algorithm that will give you active/passive semantics for your nodes: https://github.com/fivepmtechnology/MassTransit-Cluster

Furthermore, MassTransit supports introspection, diagnostics and scheduling across the control bus, having a couple of runtime services doing the hard work.

Also, Sagas, being pretty nice for coordinating distributed system computations, are supported.

A sibling to 'clustering' is 'failover', often revolving around client-server architectures; e.g. connecting to a web site - this is better done on a network level. Keepalived is smooth for that.

Finally, you can use a linux-oriented library like corosync; but for me MassTransit works well enough!

The mailing list is here https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/masstransit-discuss and docs here http://masstransit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/